# Mounting Windows 10 disk in Kali Unix USB impossible due to missing Windows disk

Tags: mount, kali-linux, windows

I'm trying to get to my admin password on my computer(Acer Nitro 5, running windows10) using a kali live usb. I already burned kali to the usb, and have booted to the kali interface, but then I can't find the disk to mount. sudo fdisk -l shows me three disks/partitions, but only one is Hidden HPFS/ntfs(the other2 are FAT and Linux) and that one just gives

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

How do I find the windows disk to mount?
Going to /proc/partitions just shows

```
major  minor  #blocks  name
8        0     30274560 sda
8        1      3273568 sda1
8        2          736 sda2
8        3      6836224 sda3
7        0      2999252 loop0
```

There's nothing in /media either that doesn't lead back to the thumbdrive either, and fuser shows nothing for any drive

Comment: The error message suggests that something is already accessing the NTFS partition. Are you sure the disk is not already automatically mounted for you by the desktop environment? It might get mounted at somewhere under `/media`.

Comment: ls /media is empty. is there a command to show potentially hidden files?

Comment: Look into `/proc/mounts` to see a list of all the mounted filesystems and their mount point locations. Or run `fuser /dev/<your NTFS partition device>` to see if some process is accessing the partition.

Comment: a closer look at fdisk's output shows me that sda1 has the boot option checked, for some reason. It has an entry in /proc/mounts and nothing in fuser/dev/sda1

Comment: I thunk sda1 is the thumbdrive itself. when I went to /proc/mounts its entry was /run/live/medium and when I went there I found some files on the thumbdrrive before I burned it. could not completely wiping my drive have caused the issue?

Comment: Yes, if it is mounted to `/run/live/medium`, it is definitely the Kali thumbdrive. No, I don't think not wiping the thumbdrive is causing your problem of not finding the Windows drive. Instead, first look into `/proc/partitions`; the Windows drive might have a non-traditional name like `/dev/nvme0n1`. Or if only the Kali thumbdrive's partitions are listed in there, then Kali might not be loading the kernel module for the appropriate disk controller.

Comment: If it is in `/proc/partitions` under an unusual name, how do I identify it as a windows drive? if it isn't, how can I find it/get kali to load the kernel module for the appropriate disk controller?

Comment: Please edit your original question to add information like the make and model of your computer, any hardware configuration details you might think applicable, and the contents of `/proc/partitions`. Without seeing the actual facts, it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: Edited my comment. Should I open up a new question "how to get Kali to load the kernel module for the appropriate disk controller"? I cam't bring this to chat as /I  don't have enough reputation

Comment: OK, so it's a laptop of the Acer Nitro 5 family, which includes both Intel and AMD CPUs and so at least two different chipsets. You might try `modprobe ahci` and then looking at `/proc/partitions` again. If the laptop is one of the newest models in the Nitro 5 family, it might be new enough that the SATA controller fails to auto-detect. Also you might run `dmesg -H`: it is a long listing with usually mostly information-only messages, but if there are any error messages, you might want to add those to your question.

Comment: modprobe ahci changed nothing in /proc/partitions. What error messages should I look for in dmesg -H? I saw two error messages(secboot: error during falcon reset and ar: init failed -110) but neither one seems to have anything to do with the disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I went to the bios system and switched the SATA controller to Ahci. When I ran fdisk -l it showed me new drives like /dev/nvme0n1. I needed to switch it back to its original setting when moving from kali to windows 10, but besides that it looks ok so far